# What would cause every thread in a .NET application to pause, other than Garbage Collection?

Tags: .net, multithreading, performance

I am working on a highly threaded .NET event processing application where the average processing time per query is in the sub-millisecond range, however every once in a while a massive spike would occur in the tens-of-millisecond range (30,000x slower).

After instrumenting the app I discovered that every once in a while, every single thread created by the application was paused for that tens-of-millisecond duration.  Lock contention was quickly eliminated as a culprit.

The next culprit that came to mind was Garbage Collection, however after instrumenting the app with System.GC.CollectionCount(2) calls it became clear that Gen2 collections are not the culprit.

What else would cause every thread in a .NET application to pause?

Comment: What type of application is this? Is it running "directly" on windows or is it hosted inside some other service (i.e. in a similar way to CLR integration in SQL Server)

Comment: It's running directly on windows.  It can run command line or hosted in a winforms app; and both show the same issue.

Comment: The CLR outputs ETW events for when it suspends managed threads as part of GC. I would look at those before ruling out GC completely.

Comment: This is entirely normal, your threads have to compete with other threads owned by other processes that run on the machine.  Just starting or bringing another process into the foreground gives the threads used by that process a priority boost.  And yours are going to lose the processor, the default thread quantum on a workstation is 45 msec.

Comment: @HansPassant I though that Windows schedules threads independent of processes.  If that's true, then in my mind it's far too coincidental for dozens of threads in the same process to be paused and resumed at roughly the exact same time (single digit microseconds) multiple times an hour.

Comment: It does.  But why would another process not be allowed to do what you do?